# React Native Flatlist not working properly with Scrollview

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

My screen have header component and tabs component. Like this;

```
<ScrollView>
  <ProfileCover/>
    <Tabs>
      <TabOne title='Posts'>
        <FlatList data={data.posts} onEndReached={this.loadMore} onEndThreshold={0.1}/>
      </TabOne>
      <TabTwo title='Likes'>
        <FlatList data={data.likes} onEndReached={this.loadMore} onEndThreshold={0.1} />
      </TabTwo>
   </Tabs>
</ScrollView>
```

When rendered screen, `loadMore` function trigger again and again. How can I use `FlatList` with `ScrollView` ?

I am tried with `ListHeaderComponent` without `ScrollView` it's working but when tabs change re-rendering all screen. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you post your `this.loadMore` function ?

Comment: its receiving with mobx like this. ProfileStore.Feed(). Btw. i'ts working without ScrollView.

Comment: what's your project react-native version